# WiX 3.8 - Debug Custom Burn Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

Can Anyone point out the steps involved in debugging a WiX Custom Burn Bootstrapper ?

I have my MSI working clean. But when I use it with Burn bootstrapper, the custom actions defer and create problems. I want to just debug my bootstrapper with VS2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug custom bootstrap application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001980/how-to-debug-custom-bootstrap-application)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rob Mensching describes the proper way in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001980/how-to-debug-custom-bootstrap-application/15913760#15913760).

Alternatively, you could use the following:

- The bootstrapper creates logs in your user's temp directory, ex: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp`
- Run your boostrapper and attach the debugger to your setup.exe.
- Call `Debugger.Launch()` (from the System.Diagnostics namespace) in your code to launch your debugger during runtime.

Comment: Note: The last option, Debugger.Launch() can be used if your bootstrapper was written using managed code.

Comment: For managed bootstrapper applications, @RobMensching explained [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15913760/1811525) of automatically attaching the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @CodeFox, that link is helpful. That is much nicer than adding Debugger.Launch() statements in the code.